# Is this freehub a Shimano or Campagnolo type?

Tags: road-bike, wheels, compatibility, campagnolo, freehub

I'm looking at purchasing a used Fulcrum Racing 5 wheelset to go with my Shimano 10 speed cassette.

The seller is unsure if the freehub is Shimano or Campagnolo but has provided pictures. Does anyone know which freehub this is? Will only the Shimano freehub work with my Shimano cassette?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google image search for 'Shimano Freehub'](https://www.google.com/search?q=shimano%20freehub&tbm=isch)

[Google image search for 'Campagnolo Freehub'](https://www.google.com/search?q=campagnolo%20freehub&tbm=isch)

Comparing images, I'd say that is a Campy freehub. Shimano Hyperglide freehubs have shallower splines.

Personally I'd be a bit cautious about a seller that doesn't know or can't provide details about the wheels.

Comment: Concur, it’s definitely a Campy freehub.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Note that you might purchase a replacement freehub body for shimano, but that cost has to weigh into the total, possibly making it not-a-deal.    Example but not a recommendation  : 
  https://www.chainreactioncycles.com/nz/en/fulcrum-shimano-sram-freehub-body/rp-prod164274